# What type of plant is this and is it a houseplant?

Tags: identification, houseplants

I came across this plant, while searching for another plant. I have no clue as to what kind of plant this is. Also, wondering if it's a houseplant as well. [image: weird looking, I'd say]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is the [burrow tail sedum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sedum_morganianum) or Sedum morganianum. This succulent plant is native to Mexico and Central America and is considered a perennial there. In areas where the temperature consistently gets below zero it is a houseplant.

The requirements are:

- high light (south facing window usually)
- free draining soil
- a clay pot is preferred as the weight will help stabilize the long tails that grow over the edge of the pot.
- reduce watering during the winter months
- the tails can get very long so place it where they can hang several feet down or more
- it propagates extremely easily, any piece of the tail if left on top of soil will root and grow
- never seen any insect or virus/fungus/bacteria problems
- do not overwater

Comment: Be sure whatever supports it is solid, I had one in a clay pot in a hanger anchored to the ceiling and the tails got 6+ feet long. Then one day after watering the weight pulled the Anchor-bolt from the ceiling. Pot, soil and plant EVERYWHERE.

Comment: What a lucky person you are to have  a plant like this.  Think tall pot support, if a new pot (not much bigger than what you've got) but go wider than tall!  Very shallow root system!  Coolness!